# C++ integer: работа с числами длиннее long long int

Tags: c++

Мне нужно работать с числами, которые не влазят в long long int, возможно ли использовать какие-то переменные для этого, или только хранить всё это в маcивах?

Comment: Храните в hex-строках, все равно для их использования нужен long-препроцессор. А сами ASCII читабельны - удобно.

Answer (score 7):

для этого придется либо писать свою библиотеку ( и реализовывать на массивах - один из вариантов). А можно поискать готовые, [например](http://www.arageli.org/). Есть [документация на русском](http://www.arageli.org/doc/ArageliUsersGuide.pdf).

Да и просто погуглить на тему BigInt, можно много найти. Например библиотеку [dlib](http://dlib.net/), где есть и работа с большими числами. А [здесь](http://ckod-doc.blogspot.com/2010_07_01_archive.html) кое-какое описание на русском.