# Аналог явовского BigInteger

Tags: c++, c++11

Есть ли в C++ аналог явовского java.math.BigInteger?

Comment: Это которое 64-битное целое или для произвольно больших чисел?

Comment: уже было. [1](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/261910/%D0%9E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0-30-%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5/261912#261912), [2](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/164243/c-integer-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5-long-long-int/164245#164245).

Comment: @KoVadim, реализации BigInteger тоже разные. Например реализация BigInteger из .NET и реализация java.math.BigInteger - разные.

Comment: Разные языки, разная реализация. Но если реализация считает, что 2+2 = 7, то какая разница, какой язык/платформа/реализация.

Comment: @KoVadim, http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/414022/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81-bigintiger-%d1%81-java-%d0%b2-c Производительность очень важна в моем случае.

Comment: @KoVadim, т.е. 2+2 = 4 в яве и 2+2 = 7 в .NET реализации.

Comment: @Alexis а вы возьмите самое простое и посмотрите, возможно, Ваша "производительность важна" не так и важна и Вам вполне хватит.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В стандартной библиотеке С++ на текущий момент - нет.

`boost::multiprecision` содержит соответствующие аналоги. Там есть как арифметика расширенной фиксированной ширины, так и динамической ("бесконечной") ширины. Там есть как С++ оболочки для GMP (последнюю надо ставить отдельно), так и собственная независимая реализация.

Answer (score 1):

Стандартом языка не предусмотрено. 
Воспользуйтесь одной из имеющихся библиотек - наподобие [GMP](https://gmplib.org/)

Comment: Как, кстати, у нее сейчас с поддержкой Visual Studio?

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/100953)

Comment: @KirillStoianov прочитайте вопрос и ответ, тут не требуется удаление.

Answer (score -1):

BigInteger - структура .NET Framework

Подойдёт?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Вы добавили пример ссылку на .NET реализацию. В метках же указан чистый C++, не CLI.